# How to Create an XML file directly from DS18B20 sensor in raspberry Pi?

Tags: python, xml, server, raspberry-pi

Can any one help me with how to generate a .xml file which can be accessed from something like http://your-raspberrypi-ip/some-filename.xml in raspberry pi for DS18B20 one wire temperature sensor.

I want to make a xml file which should be updated every 5 mins automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly what you're asking, I'm going to suggest you take a look here:

> http://www.instructables.com/id/Using-XML-on-the-Raspberry-Pi-with-Python/

If you can clarify the question a bit, I may be able to offer more assistance. Hope this helps.